# Problem with wp_editor

Tags: plugins, wp-editor

I tried to add [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) in this function but no success. Can someone help me to add wp_editor in the 'story' field..

```
    function guestposts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract ( shortcode_atts (array(
        'cat' => '1',
        'author' => '1',
        'thanks' => get_bloginfo('home'),
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<form class="guests-post" action="'. plugin_dir_url("guest-posts.php") .'guest-posts/guest-posts-submit.php" method="post">
        <strong>' . __('Post Title:', 'guest-posts') . '</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="title" size="60" required="required" placeholder="' . __('Post title here', 'guest-posts') . '"><br>
        <strong>' . __('Story', 'guest-posts') . '</strong>
        '. wp_nonce_field() .'
            <textarea rows="15" cols="72" required="required" name="story" placeholder="' . __('Start writing your post here', 'guest-posts') . '"></textarea><br>
        <strong>' . __('Tags', 'guest-posts') . '</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="tags" size="60" placeholder="' . __('Comma Separated Tags', 'guest-posts') . '"><br><br>
        <strong>' . __('Your Name', 'guest-posts') . '</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="author" size="60" required="required" placeholder="' . __('Your name here', 'guest-posts') . '"><br>
        <strong>' . __('Your Email', 'guest-posts') . '</strong><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" size="60" required="required" placeholder="' . __('Your Email Here', 'guest-posts') . '"><br>
        <strong>' . __('Your Website', 'guest-posts') . '</strong><br>
            <input type="text" name="site" size="60" placeholder="' . __('Your Website Here', 'guest-posts') . '"><br><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" value="'. $cat .'" name="category"><input type="hidden" value="'. $author .'" name="authorid">
        <input type="hidden" value="'. $thanks .'" name="thanks">
        <input type="hidden" value="'. str_replace('/wp-content/themes', '', get_theme_root()) .'/wp-blog-header.php" name="rootpath">
        <input type="submit" value="' . __('Submit The Post', 'guest-posts') . '"> <input type="reset" value="' . __('Reset', 'guest-posts') . '"><br>
        </form>
        ';
    }
add_shortcode( 'guest-posts', 'guestposts_shortcode' );

?>
```

And this is the submit.php

```
    <?php

//Get the submitted form
ob_start();
require_once($_POST["rootpath"]);
$title = $_POST["title"];
$story = $_POST["story"];
$tags = $_POST["tags"];
$author = $_POST["author"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$site = $_POST["site"];
$authorid = $_POST["authorid"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$thankyou = $_POST["thanks"];
$path = $_POST["rootpath"];
$nonce=$_POST["_wpnonce"];

//Load WordPress
//require($path);

//Verify the form fields


   //Post Properties
    $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $story,
            'post_category' => $category,  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
            'tags_input'    => $tags,
            'post_status'   => 'pending',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
            'post_type' => 'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
            'post_author' => $authorid //Author ID
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    /* Insert Form data into Custom Fields */
    add_post_meta($pid, 'author', $author, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'author-email', $email, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'author-website', $site, true);

header("Location: $thankyou");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wp_editor echos the editor including a textarea. So just replace the textarea with `<?php wp_editor($content, $id, $args); ?>` and set the arguments as you want them to be.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: Did as you said,but it returns nothing

Comment: Oh I didn't see that you are returning it... So you have to buffer it using ob_ functions.

Comment: wp-editor is added but it goes above the form :( I'm new to this,I've added the remaining part also,can you please tell me exactly how to get this work...

Comment: Replace the return with a variable (call it whatever you want, i use $return) `$return = 'here goes the form until the editor'; ob_start(); wp_editor(...); $return .= ob_get_clean(); $return .= 'and here goes the form after the editor'; return $return;`

Comment: ob_ functions is already used,now the problem is wp_editor is showing but it is not inside the form

Comment: show me your code.

Comment: '        <strong>' . __('Story', 'guest-posts') . '</strong>

             '.wp_editor('', 'guests-post', $args) .' <br>'

Comment: you have to use the ob functions for the editor only as i commented above